# ggplot - how to manually adjust labeling

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I've managed to plot "Products co-developed in certain world regions" with ggplot. 
I'd like to use the counts (not percentages) as labels.
This works well, however, the bars for some regions become so tiny that one cannot read the numbers (see on the right-bottom part of the plot).
I'd like to leave these numbers out or to display only one number (summing the counts from the regions with very low shares).
How can I manually adapt this?

```
ggplot(data1_,aes(x = year, y = products_developed_abroad_, 
                   fill = co_region)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Co-Region")) +
  labs(x="Year", y="Percentage") +
  theme_economist() + scale_fill_manual(values=colors) +
    geom_text(aes(label=products_developed_abroad_),position=position_fill(vjust=0.5), size = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide `dput(data1_)`?

Answer (score 1):

Without the data to test the solution it is a bit hard to be sure, but I would test something around the line of:

```
min_display <- 0.05
+ geom_text(aes(label=products_developed_abroad_, alpha = products_developed_abroad_ > min_display
    ),position=position_fill(vjust=0.5), size = 2) + 
scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0,1))
```

That should do the trick to leave them out, even if it's not elegant. Summing them is a bit more difficult, and may also be very confusing.

Comment: thank you. For some reasons, your suggestion did not work in my case. However, I found a solution based on http://r-statistics.co/Complete-Ggplot2-Tutorial-Part2-Customizing-Theme-With-R-Code.html (section 3) . See my answer I posted

Comment: You may want to adjust the `min_display`value (it may be 5 instead of 0.05), it may comes from that. It worked on a custom plot (as I had not your data to test your code).
This solution has the advantage to avoid modifications of the original data. 
I'm glad you found a solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is the following:

```
#first we need to calculate shares of co-region by region
data1_$shares <- data1_$products_developed_abroad_/with(data1_, ave(products_developed_abroad_, list(year), FUN = sum)) 
#we need to choose a cutoff value for the shares and set counts associated with lower shares to missing, in this case we want counts with only shares larger than 0.02 (then the remaining counts seem to be displayed properly
data1_$large_bar <- ifelse(data1_$shares > 0.02, data1_$products_developed_abroad, "")
```

The only thing we still need to do is to change geom_text:

```
geom_text(aes(label = large_bar), ...)
```